# When I excute rake db:migrate, I get version 0, I don't know what happend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I have 50 migrations files inside folder db/migrate, when I excute **rake db:migrate** always I get a schema file with version 0.

I don't unsderstand what happend.

I have tried delete all migrations file and execute **rake db:schema:load** but I can't do a new migration.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had defined a environment var named VERSION. It blocked migration task